# $Γ \models α $if and only if $Γ ∪ \{(¬α)\}$ is not satisfiable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Let $\Gamma$ be some set of well formed formulas and let $\alpha \in \mathrm{WFF}$. Prove the following
statement:

- $\Gamma \models \alpha$ if and only if $\Gamma \cup \{(\lnot\alpha)\}$ is not satisfiable.

So far I have done this:

edit: whatever I did was wrong, so can you tell me what could be done?

Comment: Seems totally off the mark.

Comment: @WilliamElliot What do you mean by totally off the mark?? can you expllain??

Comment: He means it is completely wrong, and I agree. Sorry if it's harsh, but nothing you wrote makes any sense at all.

Comment: damn can you give me hints or guide me on how to solve it??

Comment: What you mention it means to be "not satisfiable" is wrong. Usually (though I have no idea how it is defined in your class) not satisfiable means that there doesn't exist a valuation (or model) that makes true all the formulas in the set $\Gamma\cup\{\lnot a\}$. On the other hand $\Gamma\models a$ usually means that every valuation that makes all elements of $\Gamma$ true makes also $a$ true. I would recommend that you read back at the definitions and try to understand them. If you manage to clarify to yourself what these words/symbols mean, you will see that the question is not hard.